# initiate with ajax and jquery, troubles with $get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I don't understand this, I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Problema</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">

$.get("hola.html", function(respuestaSolicitud){
   alert(respuestaSolicitud);
}) 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The file hola.html contains only a string "hola hola".
The alert is showing this string: [Object XMLDocument], according a manual this should show an alert with "hola hola" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this page will help you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

And particularly this paragraph:

> The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will
>   be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object,
>   **depending on the MIME type of the response**. It is also passed the text
>   status of the response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "hola.html",
  contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data, textStatus){
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting HTML to be returned from the AJAX request, you need to specify it in the `datatype` parameter. jQuery is good at guessing the returned datatype, but can get confused between XML and HTML when only returning a portion of a HTML page.

```
$.get(
   "hola.html", 
    function(respuestaSolicitud) {
        alert(respuestaSolicitud);
    },
    dataType: "html"
);
```

Comment: Why do you need to wait for document.ready before loading some data via XHR and alerting it?

Answer (score -1):

Try getJSON instead. It seems the best for this case.

```
$.getJSON("test.html", function(json){ alert(json); });
```